# Transaction state in SQLAlchemy 2.0 with Asyncio

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

## Context

I am trying to figure out the nature of transaction management within SQLAlchemy combined with async await statements with Python asyncio.

Setup TLDR: Python 3.11, SQLAlchemy 2.0.12, asyncpg 0.28.0, PostgreSQL 14 as a database.

1. We have this simple piece of code that sets up our database engine and our `AsyncSession` factory.

```
from sqlalchemy import QueuePool
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from g.secret_config import DATABASE_URL

engine = create_async_engine(
    "postgresql+asyncpg://test-user:test-password@postgres-host:5432/test-db",
    pool_class=QueuePool,
    pool_size=1,
    max_overflow=1,
    pool_timeout=5,
    pool_recycle=600,
    connect_args={
        "timeout": 30, 
        "server_settings": {
            "application_name": "test-app",
            "options": f"-c statement_timeout=10ms"
        },
    }
)

session_factory = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)
```

2. Then, somewhere inside asyncio loop we execute the following async function ⬇️ Basically the function does nothing more than just taking a session from the pool and then using it for the queries, then closing a session when context manager exits.

```
...

async def magic_func(user_id):
    async with session_factory() as async_session:
        result_1 = await async_session.execute(select(User).where(User.id == user_id))
        user = result_1.scalar()
    

        result_2 = await async_session.execute(select(UserLog).where(UserLog.user_id == user_id))   
        log = result_2.scalar()
```

3. Finally, let's assume our asyncio eventloop has a signifcant volume of tasks coming constantly and each task should only execute the async function above.

## Question

Is this function gonna have idle-in-transaction happening each time we call `await async_session.execute`?

To my understanding, by awaiting the `async_session.execute`, it will yield control back to the event loop.
When our event loop, in favour, has a significant volume of tasks to process: the longer it will be processing other tasks, the longer the idle-in-transaction between line `result_1 = ...`  and line `user = result_1.scalar()` gonna be happening because SQLAlchemy opens implicit transaction on the first statement.

Is it correct or not? If not, what I am missing here?

Thank you!